# 301 redirection not working with %251 pattern

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a redirection that doesn't work with the pattern ^\%251 in a .htaccess file on an Apache server.

%251 is "ɑ" in hexadecimal and that redirection works ( `RewriteRule ^\ɑ.*$ http://test.example.com [R=301,L]`).

But if I try to redirect the URL that ends with "%251" (`RewriteRule ^\%251.*$ http://test.example.com [R=301,L]`), I get a page not found error ...

Does anybody know the correct syntax or the proper way to proceed for what I'm trying to do ?

Thank you !

Comment: \$251 would literally be looking for **$251**, rather than the character you think you're specifying. Maybe something like `\x251` would work? You'd have to look it up in the Apache docs to be sure. Also watch out for what _encoding_ Apache is expecting, and whether you have to explicitly specify that encoding with a flag somewhere.

Comment: My bad, it's %251, not $251 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `if I try to redirect the URL that ends with "%251"`

That rule will be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule "\%1$" http://test.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works !  Thank you very much ... but I don't understand why it isn't "\%251$" instead of "\%1$"

Comment: `\%251$` is considered encoded string and Apache decodes it to `%1` before it reaches mod_rewrite.